# How to do a JList MVC style?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jlist

I've been trying to implement a simple JList using MVC. Basicaly, show the JList and under it add a button to delete an item. I want to use AbstractListModel for the model because later on I want more than just a simple ArrayList as data.

I'm having trouble using the JList in a proper MVC way. For example in the View I create the list. But this list need the model (addModel(method), and is added in the View.
It seems weird because I thought in MVC the View had no knowledge of the model.
I also don't really know what I should put in the controller.

Anyway if someone could give me guidelines to implement this it would be nice.

Here's the code I started:

```
public class SimpleJlist extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        View view = new View(controller);
        Model model = new Model();

        SimpleJlist jl = new SimpleJlist();

        jl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jl.add(view);

        jl.setVisible(true);
        jl.pack();

    }
}

public class View extends JPanel implements ListDataListener, ActionListener
{
    Controller controller;
    JButton button;
    JList list;

    public View(Controller controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
        button = new JButton("Delete");

        /* Creation of the Jlist, but need the model. */

    }

    /* For the button */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { }
    /* For the list */
    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent event) { }
    public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent event) { }
    public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent event) { }

}

public class Model extends AbstractListModel 
{
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    public Model()
    {
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        /* add names... */
    }

    public void deleteElement(int index) { names.remove(index); }
    public String getElementAt(int index) { return names.get(index); }
    public int getSize() { return names.size(); }
}
```

The code is far from complete obviously, but this is about where I got to before wondering what to do next...

The controller is not there, because I'm simply not sure what to put in it.

Comment: What do you want to get by design the view dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying to implement a simple JList using MVC.

Swing components are already designed in an MVC like style. You just need to use the components. The LIstModel is the model and the JList is a combined view-controller. You don't create additional classes called Model-View-Controller.

> Basicaly, show the JList and under it add a button to delete an item.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for an example of how to add/remove items from the DefaultListModel

> I want to use AbstractListModel for the model because later on I want more than just a simple ArrayList as data.

That's fine, all you are doing is replacing the model. You don't need to make any changes to the JList when you do this, assuming that your model invokes the proper fireXXX() methods when the data is changed.

You should also check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Models](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) which shows how you might use the MVC approach for your own custom component.